# nextflow: channel From Path returns null even though file exists

Tags: nextflow

I wanted to create a channel with certain files as below:

```
nextflow.enable.dsl=1
channel.FromPath('/cluster/projects/p33/users/gledak/metabolomics/lipids/out/*_permuted*.glm.linear').view()
```

But it gives me error:

```
Cannot invoke method view() on null object
```

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Channel factory methods (e.g. [`fromPath`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#frompath)) and operators follow the lower camel case naming convention. What you want is:

```
Channel.fromPath('/cluster/projects/p33/users/gledak/metabolomics/lipids/out/*_permuted*.glm.linear').view()
```

Note that the old DSL1 is no longer supported.